# Can flutter isolates be safely instantiated above runApp()

Tags: flutter, isolate

Hi I instantiated an isolate for my data layer above my main app, above runApp()

I wonder what will happen when the app is minimised, will the isolate be closed. Do isolates time out anyway...

Has anyone got experience of this in a live app?

Answer (score 1):

As from [Flutter's happy recommendeations](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/packages-and-plugins/happy-paths/recommended#background-processing-) page:

> There are a of couple ways to incorporate background processing into your mobile app. One way is through a Dart isolate. With a Dart
> isolate, you can create a separate thread to run tasks concurrently in
> the background.
>
> Another way to incorporate background processing is through the
> WorkManager plugin. With this plugin, you can enable persistent
> headless execution of Dart code. Your tasks remain scheduled through
> app restarts and system reboots.

so the answer is **yes**, you can achieve running dart code in the background with `Dart` isolates, but consider also using the `workManager` package.

Comment: This is interesting thanks, but it doesn't answer of my questions. Perhaps my fault, I was a little unclear. 
1. Do isolates time out when not used for a while
2. Does minimising the app potentially terminate isolates, and are they reinstantiated when the app regains focus

Answer (score 1):

I tested the situation proposed, and the isolates were working(simply setup a timer which logs some random message to console) even if app is minimised. If the app is killed by user or by OS, isolates will be killed as well. And yes you can spawn an isolate before `runApp()`. If the isolate is required to return some data to the main isolate, I recommend making the `main()` function `async` and wait(`await`) for the completion. Flutter will not render the UI until everything before `runApp()` is completed without error.